# Commuting matrix with a non-negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I want to find two non commuting matrix $T_1$ and $T_2$ i.e. $[T_1,T_2]\neq0$ but $A[T_1,T_2]=0$ where $A$ is a non-negative matrix that is $\langle Au,u\rangle\geq0,\;\forall\;u\in \mathcal{H}$ and $A\neq0$. And thank you very much

Comment: This is done with the zero matrix: $A=0$.

Comment: But I want to find a matrix $A$ which is non zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

use:
$$T_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
T_2=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: You are welcome! And don't forget to accept if you like :)